# Chrome cookies only partly cleared when set to clear upon exit

Tags: google-chrome, browser, cookies

I must have seen the same question in this same forum but I can't find an answer. Chrome simply does not clear all cookies upon exiting, when set to do so. The only way to clear it, is by manually deleting browsing history or by deleting them individually in the cookies settings. Is this still a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use `incognito window` in chrome. In `incognito window` the cookie and history will automatically wipe after closing the browser.

Comment: Yeah, that's also an option which I am aware of but what I am really interested to know is whether this is a known issue and whether it might be fixed. One other question I have and sorry being out of discussion, are website cookies able somehow to read usernames used for other websites?